# AWS Step Functions - Parallel Execution - States.DataLimitExceeded

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I use AWS Step Functions to create a workflow which executes in one step a lambda function 100 times in parallel. The problem is that every function gives back an output which includes http headers, logs, payload etc. The parallel step combines all these outputs, and so I have reached the "States.DataLimitExceeded" which is 32,768 characters. The output of on function is about 1400 characters, so I can only run 20 functions in parallel.
Is it possible to disable the output? I don't need nothing of the output.
Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 2):

You can define which portion of the result that is transmitted to the next step. For that you have to use

`"OutputPath": "$.part2",`

In your json input you have

```
  "part1": {
    "portion1": {
      "procedure": "Delete_X"   
    },
    "portion2":{
      "procedure": "Load_X" 
    }
 },

  "part2": {
    "portion1": {
      "procedure": "Delete_Y"   
    },
    "portion2":{
      "procedure": "Load_Y" 
    }
 }
```

With this: `"OutputPath": "$.part2",`

You make sure that part1 is not sent in the output.

let me know if that helps